# How to give an addition assignment(+=) to a translate in JS(jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, assignment-operator

My expectation is to set the addition assignment operator(`+=/-=`) to the `transform: translateX()`, but have no idea how would I do this.

I've tried some ways to do this:

```
$('.inline-grid').css({transform: 'translate(+= 4%, 0)'}) 
$('.inline-grid').css({transform: 'translate(''+=' + '4' + '%', 0')'})
$('.inline-grid').css({transform: "translate("+=" + "10" + "%", 0)"})
$('.inline-grid').css({transform: '+=' + 'translateX(4%)'})
$('.inline-grid').css({transform: '+=translateX(4%)'})
```

but none of these work.

Are there any ways to give `+=` operator to the `translateX()`?

Code:

```js
function delay(callback) {
  let binding = callback.bind(this);
  setTimeout(binding, 400);
}
function action() {
  setInterval(() => {
    $('.inline-grid').css({
      transform: "translateX(10%)"
    })
    console.log(`waiting 400ms`);
  }, 1900);
}
delay(action);
```

```css
    #element{
      position : relative;
      font-size: 3rem;
      font-family: Helvetica;
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .inline-grid {
      position: relative;
      transform: translate(-10%, 0);
    }
    .transition {
      transition: all 1000ms cubic-bezier(.93,.01,.1,.98);
    }
```

```html
    <div id="element">
      <div class="inline-grid transition">
        Bazil Leaves
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `Are there any ways to give += operator to the translateX()` Not in the manner you're attempting. You would need to somehow retrieve the current value from the CSS property in to a JS variable, perform the `+=` operation in JS, then update the CSS rule with the new value from JS.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan So what I need to do is: `get translate value from the CSS file` -> `calculate it inside of JS` -> `send a new value back and override it to the CSS file`, right?

Comment: @mplungjan I won't use`animate()` method to solve my problem. As far as I know, giving the `transition` is more harder and complicate using `animate()` method instead of `.css()` or adding `classes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to @Rory's tip, I've made a simple module for resolving my problem. I share this with a short description for people who have the same problem like me in the near future.

The main feature of this module is **Unlimited Accumulating**. Unlikely `.css()` method in jQuery, the accumulation doesn't affected by the CSS's `transition` property.

Thank you for the advice @RoryMcCrossan :-)

**========= LATEST UPDATE =========**

> Now the user can accumulate any kinds of `unit` such as `px`, `cm`, `rem`,
>   even `%`.

[See in Github](https://github.com/sniffingdoggo/Unlimited-Accumulation-Module)

**========= LATEST UPDATE =========**

This code is outdated since 8/11/2019.

```js
// @BUG FIXED
// @CHANGED THE CODE MORE CLEARER
// @USAGE: Operator.assemble(target, increment, property, unit);

const Operator = (function() {
  function Accumulate(init, acc, name, unit) {
    this.init = document.querySelector(init);
    this.acc = acc;
    this.name = name;
    this.unit = unit;
    this.convert(this.result);
  }
  Accumulate.prototype = {
    convert: function(callback) {
      let defaultDisplay = this.init.style.display;
      this.init.style.display = 'none';
      let bind = callback.bind(this),
          getValues = window.getComputedStyle(this.init, null).getPropertyValue(this.name),
          S2N = parseInt(getValues, 10);
      this.init.style.display = defaultDisplay;
      bind(S2N);
    },
    result: function(value) {
      let getNewValue = value + this.acc;
      this.init.style.left = getNewValue + this.unit;
    }
  }
  return {
    assemble: (init, acc, name, unit) => {
      new Accumulate(init, acc, name, unit);
    }
  }
}());

//==============================================

setInterval(() => {
  Operator.assemble('.content', 10, 'left', '%');
}, 1000);
```

```css
  #box{
    max-width: 2560px;
    background-color: gold;
  }
  .content {
    left: 10%; /* 10px */
    position: relative;
    transition: 1000ms;
  }
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div class="content">
    wowtested
  </div>
</div>
```