# How to use CSS transition during accumulation on JS? (Code suddenly doesn't work)

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, transition, accumulate

I've been used this code for moving specific element, and for accumulating the `value` of CSS property (e.g: `left`) with `transition: cubic-bezier` at the same time. I had checked this code worked 2~3 days ago, but today now, suddenly, the `transition` doesn't work anymore for unknown reason.

This is the code:

```js
'use strict';
class Assemble {
    constructor(elem, acc, name, unit) {
        this.elem = document.querySelector(elem);
        this.acc = acc;
        this.name= name;
        this.unit = unit;
    }
    calc() {
        let displayOn = this.elem.style.display;
        this.elem.style.display = 'none';
        let currentProp = window.getComputedStyle(this.elem, null).getPropertyValue(this.name),
            S2N = parseInt(currentProp, 10);
        this.elem.style.display = displayOn;
        this.stock(S2N);
    }
    stock(value) {
        let digit = (value * 1) + this.acc;
        this.elem.style.left = digit + this.unit;
        console.log(this.elem.style.left);
    }
}
let proAssemble = new Assemble('.button', 10, 'left', '%');
setInterval(() => {
    proAssemble.calc();
}, 1500)
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.button {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    left: 10%;
    background-color: purple;
    transition: left 1000ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
    test
</div>
```

The Algorithm is Simple:

1. Turn off the `element's display` to get its current CSS property. (necessary)
2. Detach the length unit(`%`) to the CSS property value.
3. Turn on the `element's display`.
4. Add the number `this.acc` to the CSS property value.
5. Assign it to the `element`.

Just in case, I've checked the latest patch notes of [CSS](http://www.css3.info/) and [Javascript](https://javascriptweekly.com/issues/449) both but I don't know which one causes to not work it.

Any tips would be great to fix this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, have you made any changes at all in the last few days? Maybe changed a file location, a class name etc.

Comment: @ScottieG I think I haven't except copied some files for studying. But the code that I've attached on the question is totally new one. I've re-written that for checking out the glitches.

Comment: @ScottieG I'd written this code 2 months ago, and this one also doesn't work today. You can check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56446336/how-to-give-an-addition-assignment-to-a-translate-in-jsjquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably due to internal optimisations. What is happening is that the browser is batching changes to the styles and adding them all together, even if you add them separately. This means that the `left` is not being transitioned. The same happens if you try to transition *any* property together with `display: none` to something else.

If the browser was not doing this optimisation before, they are now doing it, that's why your code is broken.

There is a simple solution to this, which is to run `stock` in a callback to setTimeout, like this: `setTimeout(() => this.stock(S2N), 0);`. This opts you out of the optimisation by scheduling the change at a later time (even if it's 0ms, it's still added to the queue and not executed immediately, thus the opt out). You can see this working in the snippet below. This is the easiest fix.

Another possible solution is to calculate the percentage yourself, instead of setting the `display: none` to get the percentage value. As far as I understand, this behaviour is not well defined and it might change in the future. You could instead calculate the percentage of your left value like this:

```
Math.floor(window.innerWidth / parseInt(currentProp, 10))
```

You could do it during the instantiation of the `Assemble` object or create some kind of logic inside the class that detects if the `unit` is a percentage.

A final word of warning: transitioning `left` is rather inefficient. Try transitioning the `transform: translateX(value)` property. It's much better for rendering performance.

```js
'use strict';
class Assemble {
    constructor(elem, acc, name, unit) {
        this.elem = document.querySelector(elem);
        this.acc = acc;
        this.name= name;
        this.unit = unit;
    }
    calc() {
        let displayOn = this.elem.style.display;
        this.elem.style.display = 'none';
        let currentProp = window.getComputedStyle(this.elem, null).getPropertyValue(this.name),
            S2N = parseInt(currentProp, 10);
        this.elem.style.display = displayOn;
        if (S2N < 100) {
            setTimeout(() => this.stock(S2N), 0);
        }
    }
    stock(value) {
        let digit = (value * 1) + this.acc;
        this.elem.style.left = digit + this.unit;
        this.elem.addEventListener('transitionend', this.calc.bind(this), {once: true})
        console.log(this.elem.style.left);
    }
}
let proAssemble = new Assemble('.button', 10, 'left', '%');
proAssemble.calc();
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.button {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    left: 0;
    background-color: purple;
    transition: left 1000ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
    test
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer, but unfortunately your solution also doesn't work when I set the `left` property to 0 in CSS and set `setInterval` timer to 1 second. I've found that transition works sometimes when I use `async-await`. I will upload if I find the solution.

Comment: @sniffingdoggo I have updated the solution using the `transitionend` event to let the browser decide when to fire the function again, so without hardcoding the duration in a `setTimeout`. Note that I am stopping the recursion after we have reached the 100% to avoid running infinitely. Also, my event listener is bound with the `once` flag, to avoid a memory leak. Given the changes, you might want to change the naming of the functions. `calc` might be something like `start`, because now the function is recursive. Tested in Safari, Firefox and Chrome. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution applying @EmanueleFeliziani's answer. but it's a bit ugly.

1. Cover up the code to boolean flag for blocking until it's done.
2. Set the `setTimeout()'s timer` to at least 100. Unless, the transition would not work again when `CTRL + MWing`.

After than, it would work smoothly.

Once again, thank you for answering @EmanueleFeliziani

One last thing, I've tried to use `Math.floor` to calculate the percentage by myself, but the browser throws `infinity`. o.o

```js
'use strict';
class Assemble {
    constructor(elem, acc, name, unit) {
        this.elem = document.querySelector(elem);
        this.acc = acc;
        this.name= name;
        this.unit = unit;
        this.trigger = true;
        setInterval(() => {
            this.calc();
        }, 1000);
    }

    calc() {
        if (this.trigger) {
            this.trigger = false;
            let displayOn = this.elem.style.display;
            this.elem.style.display = 'none';
            let currentProp = window.getComputedStyle(this.elem, null).getPropertyValue(this.name),
            S2N = parseInt(currentProp, 10);
            this.elem.style.display = displayOn;
            setTimeout(() => this.stock(S2N), 100);
        }
    }
    stock(value) {
        if(!this.trigger) {
            console.log('test');
            let digit = (value * 1) + this.acc;
            this.elem.style.left = digit + this.unit;
            this.trigger = true;
        }
    }
}
let proAssemble = new Assemble('.button', 10, 'left', '%');
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.button {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    left: 0%;
    background-color: purple;
    transition: left 500ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
    test
</div>
```